# Javascript | HTML | Pie chart status

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar

I am interested in creating a progress bar in a form of a circular chart (almost like a 2D Pie chart)

An example of what I want to acheive can be seen at: http://skinarena.com (The circle chart at the left)

I am not certain on what the best compatible way to do this will be.

Things I have Tried:

- Researched canvas, but didnt lead me far.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.brightpointinc.com/clients/brightpointinc.com/library/radialProgress/index.html?source=d3js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out http://d3js.org/ - not sure how compatible it may be though with older browsers...

Comment: Perfect! Works and is compatible.